# How to make click reveal in css/js?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Just want to know how to make click reveal when I click a button the word
**"Phone"** will change to **"+971235051"**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Phone</button>
<span>+971235051</span>
```

Any hint for this?I found a toggle, But can't find for click reveal.

Thankyou

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `:focus` for this. check updated snippet below...

```css
.num, button:focus .txt  {
  display: none;
}
button:focus .num {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="txt">Phone</span>
<span class="num">+971235051</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this with jquery

```js
$('#btn').on('click', function() {
    if($('#btn').text() != 'Phone') {
        $('#btn').text('Phone');
    } else {
        $('#btn').text('+971235051');        
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="btn" class="btn btn-primary">Phone</button>
```

This with javascript

```js
function fns() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("btn");
  if (elem.innerHTML == "Phone") {
    elem.innerHTML = "+971235051";
  } else {
    elem.innerHTML = "Phone";
  }

}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="btn" onclick="fns()" class="btn btn-primary">Phone</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a function and user innerHTML to change the text of the button

```js
function changeText(elem) {
  elem.innerHTML = "+971235051"

}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="changeText(this)">Phone</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

here it is, just take advantage of the onclick event handler in JS, attach a custom function to execute n it and in the function do the text change ;)

```js
function myFunction()
{
document.getElementById("toClick").innerHTML = "+971235051";
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()" id="toClick">Phone</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

### *Sorry, this answer is off tracks*

Maybe look after the new HTML 5.1 element: `<summary>` (here goes the [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/summary)):

```
<details>
  <summary>Phone</summary>
  <p>+971235051</p>
</details>
```

If you want a more customizable way, you should try it using JQuery and the `toggleClass()` method:

*Edited the code, it was messy, sorry ^^*

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $("span").toggleClass("btn_active");
});
```

```css
span {
  display: none;
}

.btn_active {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Phone</button>
<span>+971235051</span>
```

[W3C reference](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_toggleclass.asp)

Hope it may help :)

Answer (score 1):

```html
<button type="button" id="btn" onclick="document.getElementById('btn').innerHTML = '+971235051'" class="btn btn-primary">Phone</button>
```